# I want to change value in Protobuf and then convert protobuf to Spark DataSet Row

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, protocol-buffers, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to Spark and I want to make a change in an existing protobuf. After I make change I want to map that protobuf message to a Spark Dataset Row. Since the protobuf message is complex and deeply nested.

I dont want to create a schema and then copy values, which is tedious and hard to hand code

Something like this:

```
 Dataset<Row> events = spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .load();

//call mapper
events.mapPartitions()

....
...


//mapper code

ProtoMessage.message

//create schema
StructType SCHEMA = new StructType()
        .add("value1", DataTypes.StringType, false)
        .add("value2", DataTypes.StringType, false)


//create columns
Object[] columnes = {
message.getValue1(),
message.getValue2()
....

}

//create a row
Stream.<Row>of(new GenericRowWithSchema(columns, SCHEMA));
```

However I do not know the exact number of columns (Well I do know but its nearly impossible to hand code all)
basically What I want to do is get the protobuf, change one field and then convert whole thing to a Dataset Row.

I have looked into **sparksql-protobuf**, but I want to copy values also along after inferring the schema.

I appreciate the help!